# How can I make actionListener method Dynamic

Tags: java, swing

I have a Till system, and I wish to add items to my order table (JTable) on the side of the GUI. I also want to have a running total of the order as I'm clicking each JButton. My issue is though that I can't seem to make the listener method dynamic enough for each JButton so that the total will update depending on whether an item is added or deleted on the order. It is totaling each item as it is pressed in a JTextField but it is not rounding it to the correct number of decimal places which should be 2. I've tried using DecimalFormat and it has not worked. Here is one of my listener methods. If I can get this method working properly and make it dynamic, I can apply the same principle to the rest of the listener methods. If anyone can point me in the right direction i'd be very grateful, Thank You.

```
// Small Americano ActionListener
        americanoSmall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 24";
                    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
                    java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                    int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];

                        for (int i = 0; i < colNo; i++) {
                            objects[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                        }
                        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                        model.addRow(objects);
                        Stock s = new Stock();
                        total = total + s.getItemPrice(24);
                        totalTF.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                        totalTF.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));

                    }
                    TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                    table.setModel(model);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Consider this, the total is a reflection on the information in the `TableModel`, so instead of trying to update the tally when you update the database, update the tally when the `TableModel` is changed - This provides a separation of duties and isolates the update of the tally separately from the database making it more flexible and easier to test

Comment: *"I've tried using DecimalFormat and it has not worked"* - How did it not work? What was the input, what was the output and how was it different from the expected outcome?  How did you use it? When dealing with money, it's better to either use `BigDecimal` or `long`, but that might be beyond the scope of the assigment

Comment: I tried this: DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
totalTF.setText(Double.toString(df.format(total)));

Comment: Well, ` totalTF.setText(Double.toString(df.format(total)))` is wrong, `setText` expects a `String`, `df.format` is returning a `String` representation of `total` formatted to your needs, but then you convert that back to some kind of `Double` for some unknown reasons

Comment: Okay, Im trying to total the the items that are added to the orderlist which is a JTable. These order items are being set in a JTextfield called TotalTF. i then want to take this list of items and total them and workout the change. There is a JTextfield for amount tendered and change too. All I want to do is calculate the price of the order based on the values passed from the table to the totalTF. I want to also have it dynamic enough so that if the order is edited -- ie: something is removed from the list, the total updates accordingly.  Then i click Pay to complete the order. Do you get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to also have it dynamic enough so that if the order is edited -- ie: something is removed from the list, the total updates accordingly

Add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. An event will be generated when the data is changed or a row is added or deleted. Then you just iterate through the data in the model to recalculate the total.

Don't try to keep a running total, because when you remove a row you won't know how much to remove from the total.

Comment: I have tried to implement the tableModelListener but it is not working for me at all. I think it is because my code is abit skewed. Could anyone help me as I have been stuck on this issue for days now. I'm not asking somebody to do it for me. I will re-edit the code with what I've been trying.