# Setting a Listener to a TableModel to update as required

Tags: java, swing

I am attempting to update a JTable in my GUI depending on whether a item is added or deleted. The total price in the JTextField should increment or decrement depending on the item that is removed or added. I am aware that I should use a TableModelListener to update it dynamically. I also need to set it in a total JTextField but I'm not really sure how to approach it correctly. Here is my code.

```
     package classes;

        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.GridLayout;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import java.sql.*;
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import javax.swing.Timer;
        import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
        import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
        import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
        import javax.swing.event.*;

        public class CoffeeTill_GUI extends JFrame {

            private JPanel contentPane;
            JLabel orderDescription = new JLabel("Order Description:");
            private JTextField totalTF;
            private double total = 0.0;
            private double tendered = 0.0;
            private double change = 0.0;
            private TableModelListener tableModelListener;

            // Editing An Order
            //TableModelListener to listen for changes in the tableModel
                    private void setTableModelListener() {
                        tableModelListener = new TableModelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                                if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                                    System.out.println("Cell " + e.getFirstRow() + ", "
                                            + e.getColumn() + " changed. The new value: "
                                            + table.getModel().getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(),
                                            e.getColumn()));
                                    int row = e.getFirstRow();
                                    int column = e.getColumn();
                                    if (column == 0 || column == 1) 
                                    {
                                        TableModel model = table.getModel();
                                        int quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 0)).intValue();
                                        double price = ((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 1)).doubleValue();
                                        Double value = new Double(quantity * price);
                                        model.setValueAt(value, row, 1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(tableModelListener);
                    }

            // JDBC Driver name and database URL
            final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/team_project?useSSL=false";
            final String USER_NAME = "root";
            final String PASSWORD = "password";

            // sql variables
            Statement statement = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            // Update JTable when JButton is clicked
            public void updateTable(int prodIn) {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);

                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String sqlString = "select ProductID, ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = " + prodIn;
                    stmt.executeQuery(sqlString);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // creating new stock item
            Stock productPrice = new Stock();
            Stock productName = new Stock();
            JTable table = new JTable();

            JButton delButton = new JButton("DEL");
            JButton minusButton = new JButton("-");
            JButton plusButton = new JButton("+");

            /**
             * Launch the application.
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            CoffeeTill_GUI frame = new CoffeeTill_GUI();
                            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                            frame.setUndecorated(false);
                            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            // Connection Object
            Connection connection = null;
            private JTextField tenderedTF;
            private JTextField changeTF;

            /**
             * Create the frame.
             */
            public CoffeeTill_GUI() {
                try {
                    connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setBounds(100, 100, 1200, 686);
                contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                setContentPane(contentPane);
                contentPane.setLayout(null);

                // COFFEE PANEL - START -----------------------------------------
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
                tabbedPane.setBounds(20, 74, 796, 563);
                contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                tabbedPane.addTab("Coffee", null, panel, null);
                panel.setLayout(null);

                JLabel lblCoffee = new JLabel("Americano");
                lblCoffee.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                lblCoffee.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                lblCoffee.setBounds(10, 45, 154, 45);
                panel.add(lblCoffee);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Cappucino");
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                label.setBounds(10, 117, 154, 45);
                panel.add(label);

                JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Espresso");
                label_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                label_1.setBounds(10, 191, 154, 45);
                panel.add(label_1);

                JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Latte");
                label_2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                label_2.setBounds(10, 274, 154, 45);
                panel.add(label_2);

                JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Mocha");
                label_3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                label_3.setBounds(10, 355, 154, 45);
                panel.add(label_3);

                JLabel label_4 = new JLabel("Macchiato");
                label_4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                label_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                label_4.setBounds(10, 440, 154, 45);
                panel.add(label_4);

                JButton americanoSmall = new JButton("SMALL");
                americanoSmall.setBounds(191, 45, 164, 45);
                panel.add(americanoSmall);

                JButton americanoMedium = new JButton("MEDIUM");
                americanoMedium.setBounds(365, 45, 164, 45);
                panel.add(americanoMedium);

                JButton americanoLarge = new JButton("LARGE");
                americanoLarge.setBounds(539, 45, 164, 45);
                panel.add(americanoLarge);

                JButton cappuchinoSmall = new JButton("SMALL");
                cappuchinoSmall.setBounds(191, 117, 164, 45);
                panel.add(cappuchinoSmall);

                JButton cappuchinoMedium = new JButton("MEDIUM");
                cappuchinoMedium.setBounds(365, 117, 164, 45);
                panel.add(cappuchinoMedium);

                JButton cappuchinoLarge = new JButton("LARGE");
                cappuchinoLarge.setBounds(539, 117, 164, 45);
                panel.add(cappuchinoLarge);

                JButton espressoSmall = new JButton("SMALL");
                espressoSmall.setBounds(191, 191, 164, 45);
                panel.add(espressoSmall);

                JButton espressoMedium = new JButton("MEDIUM");
                espressoMedium.setBounds(365, 191, 164, 45);
                panel.add(espressoMedium);

                JButton espressoLarge = new JButton("LARGE");
                espressoLarge.setBounds(539, 191, 164, 45);
                panel.add(espressoLarge);

                JButton latteSmall = new JButton("SMALL");
                latteSmall.setBounds(191, 274, 164, 45);
                panel.add(latteSmall);

                JButton latteMedium = new JButton("MEDIUM");
                latteMedium.setBounds(365, 274, 164, 45);
                panel.add(latteMedium);

                JButton latteLarge = new JButton("LARGE");
                latteLarge.setBounds(539, 274, 164, 45);
                panel.add(latteLarge);

                JButton mochaSmall = new JButton("SMALL");
                mochaSmall.setBounds(191, 355, 164, 45);
                panel.add(mochaSmall);

                JButton mochaMedium = new JButton("MEDIUM");
                mochaMedium.setBounds(365, 355, 164, 45);
                panel.add(mochaMedium);

                JButton mochaLarge = new JButton("LARGE");
                mochaLarge.setBounds(539, 355, 164, 45);
                panel.add(mochaLarge);

                JButton macchiatoSmall = new JButton("SMALL");
                macchiatoSmall.setBounds(191, 440, 164, 45);
                panel.add(macchiatoSmall);

                JButton macchiatoMedium = new JButton("MEDIUM");
                macchiatoMedium.setBounds(365, 440, 164, 45);
                panel.add(macchiatoMedium);

                JButton macchiatoLarge = new JButton("LARGE");
                macchiatoLarge.setBounds(539, 440, 164, 45);
                panel.add(macchiatoLarge);
                // COFFEE PANEL - END -----------------------------------------

                // COLD DRINKS PANELS - START -----------------------------------------
                JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
                tabbedPane.addTab("Cold Drinks", null, panel_1, null);
                panel_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
                ImageIcon waterIcon, cokeIcon, spriteIcon, fantaIcon;
                JButton waterButton, cokeButton, spriteButton, fantaButton;

                panel_1.add(waterButton = new JButton(waterIcon = new ImageIcon("image/water.jpg")));
                panel_1.add(cokeButton = new JButton(cokeIcon = new ImageIcon("image/coke.jpg")));
                panel_1.add(spriteButton = new JButton(spriteIcon = new ImageIcon("image/sprite.jpg")));
                panel_1.add(fantaButton = new JButton(fantaIcon = new ImageIcon("image/fanta.jpg")));
                // COLD DRINKS PANEL - END -----------------------------------------

                // SANDWICHES - START -----------------------------------------
                JButton hamAndCheese, bltButton, tunaAndSweetcorn, chickenAndHam, hamAndCheesePanini;

                JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
                tabbedPane.addTab("Sandwiches", null, panel_2, null);
                panel_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
                panel_2.add(hamAndCheese = new JButton("Ham & Cheese"));
                panel_2.add(bltButton = new JButton("BLT"));
                panel_2.add(tunaAndSweetcorn = new JButton("Tuna & Sweetcorn"));
                panel_2.add(chickenAndHam = new JButton("Chicken & Ham"));
                panel_2.add(hamAndCheesePanini = new JButton("Ham & Cheese Panini"));
                // SANDWICHES - END -----------------------------------------

                // PASTRIES - START -----------------------------------------
                JButton danishPastryJbt, muffinJbt, cinnamonRoleJbt, profiteroleJbt, eclairJbt, croissantJbt;
                JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
                panel_3.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
                tabbedPane.addTab("Pastries", null, panel_3, null);
                panel_3.add(danishPastryJbt = new JButton("Danish Pastry"));
                panel_3.add(muffinJbt = new JButton("Muffin"));
                panel_3.add(cinnamonRoleJbt = new JButton("Cinnamon Role"));
                panel_3.add(profiteroleJbt = new JButton("Profiterole"));
                panel_3.add(eclairJbt = new JButton("Eclair"));
                panel_3.add(croissantJbt = new JButton("Croissant"));

                orderDescription.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                orderDescription.setBounds(845, 55, 214, 33);
                contentPane.add(orderDescription);
                // ORDER - END -----------------------------------------

                // HEADING - START -----------------------------------------
                JLabel lblUserEmployee = new JLabel("User: Employee1");
                lblUserEmployee.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                lblUserEmployee.setBounds(20, 11, 204, 33);
                contentPane.add(lblUserEmployee);

                JLabel lblJavaHouseCoffee = new JLabel("Java House Coffee");
                lblJavaHouseCoffee.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                lblJavaHouseCoffee.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                lblJavaHouseCoffee.setBounds(333, 11, 480, 60);
                contentPane.add(lblJavaHouseCoffee);

                // Setting the Time on the GUI
                JLabel lblTime = new JLabel("");
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                lblTime.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                lblTime.setBounds(650, 0, 120, 30);
                lblTime.setText(timeStamp + "");
                lblTime.setVisible(true);
                int delay = 1000; // milliseconds
                ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                                .format(new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        lblTime.setText("" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    }
                };
                new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();

                lblTime.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                lblTime.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                lblTime.setBounds(914, 11, 244, 45);
                contentPane.add(lblTime);

                // add header of the table
                String columns[] = new String[] { "Product Name", "Price" };
                DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
                dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
                table.setModel(dtm);

                // round the prices values pulled from DB to 2 Decimal Places
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new DecimalFormatRenderer());
                getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
                table.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 18));

                // add header of the table
                JScrollPane scrollPaneTable = new JScrollPane(table);
                scrollPaneTable.setBounds(845, 94, 329, 241);
                contentPane.add(scrollPaneTable); 

                JPanel panel_5 = new JPanel();
                scrollPaneTable.setColumnHeaderView(panel_5);
                panel_5.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JLabel totalJLabel = new JLabel("Total €");
                totalJLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                totalJLabel.setBounds(899, 400, 63, 45);
                contentPane.add(totalJLabel);

                totalTF = new JTextField();
                totalTF.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                totalTF.setBounds(970, 400, 204, 45);
                contentPane.add(totalTF);
                totalTF.setColumns(10);
                totalTF.setEditable(false);
                delButton.setBounds(845, 346, 96, 45);
                contentPane.add(delButton);

                delButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                minusButton.setBounds(963, 346, 96, 45);
                contentPane.add(minusButton);

                minusButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                plusButton.setBounds(1083, 346, 87, 45);
                contentPane.add(plusButton);

                plusButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));

                JLabel tenderedJLabel = new JLabel("Tendered €");
                tenderedJLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                tenderedJLabel.setBounds(858, 456, 102, 45);
                contentPane.add(tenderedJLabel);

                tenderedTF = new JTextField();
                tenderedTF.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                tenderedTF.setBounds(972, 456, 202, 45);
                contentPane.add(tenderedTF);
                tenderedTF.setColumns(10);

                JLabel changeJlabel = new JLabel("Change €");
                changeJlabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                changeJlabel.setBounds(878, 521, 84, 37);
                contentPane.add(changeJlabel);

                changeTF = new JTextField();
                changeTF.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                changeTF.setEditable(false);
                changeTF.setBounds(972, 512, 202, 46);
                contentPane.add(changeTF);
                changeTF.setColumns(10);

                // Delete row from JTable when clicked by user
                delButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int viewIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                        if (viewIndex != -1) {
                            // converts the row index in the view to the appropriate
                            // index in the model
                            int modelIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewIndex);
                            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            model.removeRow(modelIndex);
                        }
                    }
                });
                table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

                // HEADING - END -----------------------------------------

                // Small Americano ActionListener
                americanoSmall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 24";
                            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                            // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
                            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                            int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];

                                for (int i = 0; i < colNo; i++) {
                                    objects[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                                }
                                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                                model.addRow(objects);
                                Stock s = new Stock();
                                // deduct stock from db from
                                // s1.deductStock(24);
                                total = total + s.getItemPrice(24);
                                totalTF.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                                totalTF.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));

                            }
                            TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            table.setModel(model);
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                americanoMedium.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 25";
                            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                            // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
                            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                            int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];

                                for (int i = 0; i < colNo; i++) {
                                    objects[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                                }
                                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                                model.addRow(objects);
                                Stock s = new Stock();
                                // deduct stock from db from
                                // s1.deductStock(24);
                                total = total + s.getItemPrice(25);
                                totalTF.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                                totalTF.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));
                            }
                            TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            table.setModel(model);

                        } catch (Exception e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                americanoLarge.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 26";
                            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                            // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
                            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                            int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];
                                for (int i = 0; i < colNo; i++) {
                                    objects[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                                }
                                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                                model.addRow(objects);
                                Stock s = new Stock();
                                // deduct stock from db from
                                // s1.deductStock(24);
                                total = total + s.getItemPrice(26);
                                totalTF.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                                totalTF.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));
                            }
                            TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            table.setModel(model);

                        } catch (Exception e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                cappuchinoSmall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 30";
                            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                            // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
                            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                            int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];

                                for (int i = 0; i < colNo; i++) {
                                    objects[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                                }
                                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                                model.addRow(objects);
                                Stock s = new Stock();
                                // deduct stock from db from
                                // s1.deductStock(24);
                                total = total + s.getItemPrice(30);
                                totalTF.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                                totalTF.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));
                            }
                            TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            table.setModel(model);
                        } catch (Exception e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                cappuchinoMedium.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 31";
                            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                            // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
                            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                            int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];

                                for (int i = 0; i < colNo; i++) {
                                    objects[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                                }
                                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                                model.addRow(objects);
                                Stock s = new Stock();
                                // deduct stock from db from
                                // s1.deductStock(24);
                                total = total + s.getItemPrice(31);
                                totalTF.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                                totalTF.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));
                            }
                            TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            table.setModel(model);
                        } catch (Exception e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                cappuchinoLarge.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 32";
                            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                            // Loop through the ResultSet and transfer in the Model
                            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                            int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                            while (rs.next()) {
                                Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];

                                for (int i = 0; i < colNo; i++) {
                                    objects[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                                }
                                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                                model.addRow(objects);
                                Stock s = new Stock();
                                // deduct stock from db from
                                // s1.deductStock(24);
                                total = total + s.getItemPrice(32);
                                totalTF.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                                totalTF.setText(String.format("%.2f", total));

                            }
                            TableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            table.setModel(model);
                        } catch (Exception e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JButton payButton = new JButton("Pay");
                payButton.setBounds(970, 569, 209, 51);
                contentPane.add(payButton);;

}// end class
```

Comment: One thing I would do, is try and maintain a running tally.  This is, calculate the total amount when you first load the table, when one or more rows are deleted, decrease the tally by the sum of those rows, when one or more rows are added, increase the tally by the sum of those rows, this way, you're not constantly iterating over the `TableModel`, which may be slow

Comment: I was told not to do that as I can't be sure at any given time what amount is coming off a total. Could you give me an example and I will attempt to implement it myself to determine if it works?

Comment: The only reason you wouldn't know is if the model and view have become desynchronised

Comment: @Movillian `I was told not to do that` - yes that was me. By the way you are welcome for the help on you last question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265865/how-can-i-make-actionlistener-method-dynamic). You didn't bother to "accept" the answer or even comment with a thank you even though you are using the suggestion. I suggested a simple recalculation given the amount of data  I suspected you would have would be minimal..

Comment: Also in many examples like this you may also have a "change" function where you change a quantity and you won't have a reference to the previous quantity so won't know how much to adjust the amount by. I think keeping a cache of the data is extra overhead that adds another level of complexity. One of the rules of development is not to over optimize unless there is a performance problem. I doubt you will have a problem adding numbers in a simple loop. Pressing an Add/Remove button is not something that happens hundreds of times a second.

Answer (score 1):

So this is very basic proof of concept.

What this does is, it maintains an internal "proxy"/"cache" of the values which are added/removed/updated.  In this way, it's capable of using the event information to simply update the tally without having to re-iterate the model, which can be time consuming.

When you create a new model, you should attach the the listener to it, BEFORE populating it, this will give the listener the opportunity to be notified of new rows and update its internal state.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private DefaultTableModel model;
        private JTextField tallyField;
        private double tally;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            tallyField = new JTextField(10);
            // When loading data, update this value to represent the total
            // of the data that was loaded
            tally = 0;
            model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Quanity", "Amount"}, 0);
            model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

                private Map<Integer, Double> proxy = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
                private NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

                @Override
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                    int firstRow = e.getFirstRow();
                    int lastRow = e.getLastRow();
                    double sum = 0;
                    for (int row = Math.min(firstRow, lastRow); row <= Math.max(firstRow, lastRow); row++) {
                        switch (e.getType()) {
                            case TableModelEvent.DELETE:
                                sum -= delete(row);
                                break;
                            case TableModelEvent.INSERT:
                                sum += add(row);
                                break;
                            case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                                sum -= delete(row);
                                sum += add(row);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    tally += sum;
                    tallyField.setText(nf.format(tally));
                }

                protected double delete(int row) {
                    double sum = 0;
                    if (proxy.containsKey(row)) {
                        sum = proxy.get(row);
                    }
                    proxy.remove(row);
                    return sum;
                }

                protected double add(int row) {
                    int qty = 0;
                    // I hope your model is better setup then mine
                    if (model.getValueAt(row, 0) instanceof String) {
                        qty = Integer.parseInt((String) model.getValueAt(row, 0));
                    } else if (model.getValueAt(row, 0) instanceof Integer) {
                        qty = (Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 0);
                    }
                    double amount = (Double) model.getValueAt(row, 1);
                    double rowTotal = qty * amount;
                    proxy.put(row, rowTotal);
                    return rowTotal;
                }
            });

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JButton add = new JButton("Add");
            JButton delete = new JButton("Delete");

            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    double amount = 1.0; //Math.random() * 1000.0;
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{1, amount});
                }
            });
            delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
                    List<Integer> selection = new ArrayList<>(rows.length);
                    for (int row : rows) {
                        selection.add(row);
                    }
                    Collections.sort(selection);
                    Collections.reverse(selection);
                    for (int row : selection) {
                        model.removeRow(row);
                    }
                }
            });

            JPanel footer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.add(add);
            buttons.add(delete);

            footer.add(tallyField);
            footer.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            add(footer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

    }
}
```

Why do we need the cache?  Because when a row is deleted, you can no longer determine it's value.

If I was doing this in a real application, I would make a simple class that implements `TableModelListener` but which provided a getter to retrieve the `tally` (so the `tally` becomes encapsulated to the class) and use an observer pattern to generate notifications when the `tally` is changed.

This means that when you load the data, you can update the model and "tally monitor" independently.  And when you need to, update the required fields on the screen.

This can become very complicated, very quickly.  I did something simular to produce a automatic tallying system for tallying rows and columns independently of the model, so the system wasn't coupled to the model structure apart from known which row/column it was responsible for tallying

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this as Im completely lost to be honest

Comment: @Movillian, `Is there an easier way to do this` - you were given the easier way in your previous question. I also clarified my reasons for the simpler solution in my above comments. Learn one concept at a time. In this case you are learning now to use a TableModelListener to listen for changes to the data. So implement the simple solution first. If there is a performance issue then you can look at a more complex solution. Based on all your previous questions this is just a simple "Cash Register". Iterating through the model to add a dozen or so entries will not be an issue.

Comment: @Movillian The simpler solution would to work with the layer between the data and the model. Using the TableModelListener in this way is a more generalised approach which is more reusable and flexible