# Show total sum of column values in jtable

Tags: java, user-interface

How do I show the total sum of the values inside a table using a `JLabel`? I have tried to use the code I found in youtube but the output remains at zero value.

Here is the code

```
   double total = 0;
       for (int k = 0; k < RecTable.getRowCount(); k++) {
           int amt = Integer.parseInt(RecTable.getValueAt(k, 3).toString());
           total+=amt;
       }   
       
       totalsum.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: Well, since we don't have a runnable example which demonstrates your issue, you might find something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334278/setting-a-listener-to-a-tablemodel-to-update-as-required/43334813#43334813) helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem about scope of local variable because amt is just declared in the for loop.

```
double total = 0;
int amt = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < RecTable.getRowCount(); k++) {
    amt = Integer.parseInt(RecTable.getValueAt(k, 3).toString());
    total+=amt;
}   

totalsum.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

How about this code? Does it work?